# FlutterError: The method 'FocusTrapArea' isn't defined for the class '_PinputState'

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

i am getting the following error whenever i am using the pinput widget.

can anyone help me with this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this??

Comment: what is your flutter version ? This error If you had no problem before and now this problem has occurred , may be raised for flutter update. Because I changed the version of Flutter and it was solved for me.

Answer (score 0):

In the Github projects they explained it in Flutter stable version has a problem. Please change the pinput dependency. Tkko mentioned that it will be fixed next release. Flutter team fixed issue we are waiting Tkko release.

pinput:
git:
url: https://github.com/Tkko/Flutter_Pinput
ref: dev

https://github.com/Tkko/Flutter_Pinput/issues/116

[Pinput link](https://github.com/Tkko/Flutter_Pinput/issues/116)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug before, and here is the correct asnwer for that :

In `pubspec.yaml` file change your `pinput` depandancy to :

```
pinput:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/Tkko/Flutter_Pinput
```